Disassembly output of data and rodata sections (x86_64, nasm)
I've been playing a bit with assembly for a while and I think I have an okay grasp on it. I can write simple things in it, and I can read it okay.
Now I want to try a bit of machine code.
So, I wrote some simple snippet of x64 assembly using NASM(-O0 optimizations), and objdump'd it.
The disassembly of code section is pretty straight forward. And I think I understand everything what happens there.
But when it comes to rodata and data section I'm a bit puzzled here.
Code:
;-----------------------------------------;
section .rodata

msg db "Hello, world!",0x0A
msglen equ $-msg

;-----------------------------------------;                                                                                                                                  
section .data

b64 dq 1
b32 dd 2
b16 dw 3
b8  db 4

Disassembly:
Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000400174 <msg>:
  400174:   48                      rex.W
  400175:   65 6c                   gs ins BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
  400177:   6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[rdi],dx
  400178:   6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
  400179:   2c 20                   sub    al,0x20
  40017b:   77 6f                   ja     4001ec <msg+0x78>
  40017d:   72 6c                   jb     4001eb <msg+0x77>
  40017f:   64 21 0a                and    DWORD PTR fs:[rdx],ecx

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000600184 <b64>:
  600184:   01 00                   add    DWORD PTR [rax],eax
    ...

0000000000600188 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
  600188:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
    ...

000000000060018c <b32>:
  60018c:   02 00                   add    al,BYTE PTR [rax]
    ...

0000000000600190 <b16>:
  600190:   03 00                   add    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]

0000000000600192 <b8>:
  600192:   04                      .byte 0x4

I will leave the code section out - it's a lot of mov and add mnemonics to check for different machine instructions with registers rax-al rbx-al, then system call write(hello world) and system call exit. Nothing fancy.
Now, about the data sections.
As you can probably see, I have declared a string "Hello, world!\n" in rodata section, it's length, and four numbers in data section going from 64-bit value down to 8-bit value.
The only thing I understand are addresses. And maybe b8 value(.byte 0x4). Just a byte of certain value. Everything else is a mystery for me.
Let's start with a string.
What is rex.W? is it somehow related to 64-bit registers?
After that, it seems as if the literal string is got from some port and put at the specified memory location. Probably linker or assembler itself has put the string into some table/segment and then the string is moved to the specified address.
After that, the length is probably calculated.
It's only assumptions, so I don't really know what happens here.
Now, to the b64.
Does rax has address of b64 at the moment? If that is so, then why is eax added to it?
If someone will be able to explain what is going on there in detail down to the single instruction - I'd much appreciate that. Thanks in advance.

What is rex.W? is it somehow related to 64-bit registers? After that, it seems as if the literal string is got from some port and put at the specified memory location. No. This assembly code is your string. Your disassembler tried to disassemble data which is not machine code - your string - and thats the result.

@tkausl Damn. SIlly me. Thanks, man. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

There don't seem to be any exact duplicate Q&As; google for site:stackoverflow.com "rex.W" "gs ins" found a few questions that included disassembly of the ASCII bytes of Hello, world!, but none that were about that.  But I found What is this line in my objdump? which is essentially the same thing: disassembling other ASCII bytes, i.e. showing how a CPU would interpret them as machine code. edit: found a better duplicate about disassembling .rodata.
